# What’s the Latin word for “information”?

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice, noun

I'm creating a Latin quiz game and want to know the best word/noun for “information”. The word will be used as a title for an information/welcome page on my quiz. I searched the word on the internet and got lots of results, but wasn't sure which one is the best.

Results:

- *informatio*
- *indicium*
- *nuntium*
- *nuntiatio*
- *significantia*
- *notitia*

Comment: Given the many senses of the English word information, I doubt that one Latin word fits them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be the title for an information or welcome page, I suggest either of the following:

> *Pagina domestica* — Home page
>   *Pagina salutatoria* — Welcome page (more literally: Greeting page)

Neither means "information", but these are the Latin titles I would recommend for the kind of use you describe.
You can also use shorter variants of these suggestions:

> *Domus* — Home
>   *Salve!* — Welcome! (more literally: Greetings!)

Comment: I was thinking he meant the "About..." page.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer That crossed my mind, but since he also included "welcome page" in the description, I thought it was more of a home page than a separate "about" page. (I doubt it would work well to translate the page title "About" as "De"...) We'll have to wait for Lypyrhythm to comment on the matter to be sure.

Comment: No, it should be more like a “welcome page”. Marked as most helpful post.

Answer (score 4):

I don't feel that any of the words you found quite capture the sense of information that you want (an 'information page').  For some of them, the information is more like evidence, or an accusation.  Others are the 'information' given by an augur reading the omens.  Still others are simply the information contained in an announcement.  None of them capture the sense of information as description and explanation.

However, perhaps the following could help:

[***expositio***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=expositio&la=la#lexicon) - a statement, description; a definition

[***explicatio***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=explicatio&la=la#lexicon) - an explanation; a description, account

You could combine the best of both worlds and have these as subheadings on your welcome page/*pagina salutatoria* (if you choose to use Joonas Ilmavirta's excellent answer).